# Why can't I Interact with a Django Form Element Via Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I have the following search form rendered into an HTML template.

```
<form id="resource-search-form" action="{% url 'stock:resource_search_view' %}" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="text" name="query" id="id_query" maxlength="50">
      <button class="btn btn-success" style='position:relative;top:-10px;left:-72px;'>Search</button>
</form>
```

The issue is whenever I try to interact with the element via some sort of JavaScript, the command is basically "ignored". To illustrate, I've added another input just below the form, and attempted to interact with it the same way and it works as expected.

```
<input id="test" type="text" name="test" maxlength="50">
```

I can confirm this because I used the following to demonstrate:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#id_query').val("This doesn't work");
    $('#test').val("This does work");
  });
```

And whoa and behold, the input with id test had the value "This does work" inside it, while id_query was blank...

Can someone please enlighten me as to why this is occurring, and provide a solution to the problem?

Comment: is there anything else with an id of `id_query` on the page? is the form inserted dynamically into the dom via javascript? what does `$('#resource-search-form').children()` yield?

Comment: @LegenJerry, you were right. I used the same search form in two places on the page, and that caused the issue!

Comment: Not sure why your code isn’t working. You could try vanilla js `document.getElementById(“id_query”).value = “this doesn’t work”`. Otherwise could be a conflict with Id names. Maybe try changing the name of the id

Comment: To demonstrate http://jsfiddle.net/wy8kLqux/4/

Comment: @LegenJerry, I tried that before posting here but to no avail (kind of). I realized after reading your response that the code was working all along, however it was being applied to some a form in a modal, which was of course off-screen. Therefore causing me to believe nothing was happening, and thus here we are.